# Prove $\exists (\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_m) \in \mathcal{L}(V, \mathbf{F}) : T(v) = \varphi_1(v)w_1 + \cdots + \varphi_m(v)w_m$, $\forall v \in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$, and $(w_1, \ldots, w_m)$ is a basis of $\operatorname{range}(T)$. Prove that there exists $(\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_m) \in \mathcal{L}(V, \mathbf{F})$ such that $$ T(v) = \varphi_1(v)w_1 + \cdots + \varphi_m(v)w_m $$ for every $v \in V$.

$V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $F$.

My initial attempt to this question is as follows:

$(w_1, \ldots, w_m)$ is a basis for $\operatorname{range}(T)$. Therefore we can write $T(v)$ as $$ T(v) = \alpha_1 w_1 + \cdots + \alpha_m w_m $$ where $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m \in \mathbf{F}$.

Define $\varphi_i(v) = \alpha_i$ for $i=1, \ldots,m$.

At this point I became stuck. How am I suppose to show that for **every** choice of $v$, my definition for $\varphi_i$ is going to give the correct value or $\alpha_i$?

After looking at the answer, they just continue on from where I became stuck to show all $\varphi_i$ are linear maps. But, this just shows that $\varphi_i$ is a linear map, not that it exists or satisfies the given condition?

Comment: It seems like you're feeling a little vague on whether the $\alpha_i$ are constants or functions of $v$. In your definition (which is a good one), $\alpha_i$ definitely depends on which $v$ you're using, so they're functions of $v$. In other words, the functions $\alpha_i$ are certainly candidates for the functions $\varphi_i$ the problem is seeking. Is this answering the question you're asking?

Comment: In order to address existence: A map exists once you have defined in some way what it must do to each input. There is no inherent contradiction as you are not assigning multiple values for the same input $v$. So now that you have defined a map, if you can show it is linear, that should be enough!

Comment: @GregMartin What's confusing me, is that take for example $\varphi_1$. For every value of $v$ we give it, it must output the 'correct' constant. But not only that, we must ensure the same is true for $\varphi_2$, $\varphi_3$ and so on. Additionally, I don't see how there is no 'link' between the definitions for the various $\varphi$ - surely the values of each depend on the other? Finally, if all we are doing is saying $\varphi_i(v) = \alpha_i(v)$, what is the point in making such a definition?

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg But I could define a map $\varphi_i(v) = 0$. It's a linear map, it exists, but it's wrong?

Comment: @gorgonolo My comment was addressing your existence concern. The fact that your map works is taken care of by the way you chose it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach:

Given $v\in V$, let $\Phi(v)\in F^m$ be the unique $m$-tuple such that
$$
T(v)=(\Phi(v))_1w_1+\dots+(\Phi(v))_mw_m
$$
where we write $x_i$ for the $i$th entry of the tuple $x$. This definition makes sense because $w_1,\dots,w_m$ form a basis.

Let $\varphi_i(v):=(\Phi(v))_i$.

You can either check that $\varphi_i$ is linear by hand, or argue that $\Phi$ is linear and that $\varphi_i=\pi_i\circ \Phi$, where $\pi_i:F^m\to F$ is the $i$th projection, which is also linear.

Comment: So each $\varphi_{i}$ would be the composition of three linear transformations: $\varphi_{i} = \pi_{i} \circ \Phi \circ T$. Since the composition of two linear transformations is also a linear transformation, the results follows. This is a nice solution.

Comment: @KevinLópezAquino I'm actually taking $\Phi$ to have domain $V$, but you can also take $\Phi$ to be the canonical isomorphism $W\cong F^m$, in which case we'd have to also compose by $T$. And thanks!

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that $\Phi$ takes a $v$ from $V$. But you're right, that's what I thought when I saw it.